# I get an invalid identifier error in SQL while trying to make a PIVOT table

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT ProdName, Sales, 
    1 AS January, 2 AS February, 3 AS March, 4 AS April, 5 AS May, 6 AS June,
    7 AS July, 8 AS August, 9 AS September, 10 AS October,
    11 AS November, 12 AS December 
FROM
(SELECT actsales as Sales , EXTRACT (month from factdate) as Month, ProdName
FROM factcoffee, prodcoffee
WHERE factcoffee.ProductId = prodcoffee.productid) 
PIVOT  
(  
SUM (Sales)  
FOR Month IN  
( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 )  
);
```

I get the error for the Sales in line 1. If I remove sales from line 1 only, I get the pivot table of products as rows and the months as columns, as required, but the values are not the sales but are just 1 for january column, 2 for february column and so on.
If I do SELECT * in line 1, I get the correct sales value by month for each product. But the column names are obviously not the month names and just 1,2,...

Comment: you mean the query if you change to `SELECT *`, it does execute and gives you result ? And not syntax error ?

Comment: Just notice you uses `EXTRACT()`. I am not aware that is available `Microsoft SQL Server` or are you using `MySQL` or `Oracle` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine, but try to make it more readable

```
SELECT ProdName
, Sales
,[1] AS January
,[2] AS February
,[3] AS March
,[4] AS April
,[5] AS May
,[6] AS June
,[7] AS July
,[8] AS August
,[9] AS September
,[10] AS October
,[11] AS November
,[12] AS December 
 FROM
         (SELECT actsales as Sales , EXTRACT (month from factdate) as Month, 
          ProdName
          FROM factcoffee, prodcoffee
          WHERE factcoffee.ProductId = prodcoffee.productid) 
PIVOT  
(  
SUM (Sales)  
FOR Month IN  
( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12] )  
) as PVT;
```

Do not forget to rename pivot as PVT or another thing. Sometimes code fails for doing that or forgetting brackets.

Also if you can try to use join instead of `FROM factcoffee, prodcoffee.` It is more readable

Comment: I tried using as PVT; as you said. But I got an error "SQL Command not properly ended'. And when I add the square brackets to the numbers, I get a "missing expression" error at the very first square bracket. I'm just not sure why the code isn't working...